# ImageMagick install fails on "verification" step in OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, install, macports

I’ve just tried to install ImageMagick on OS X 10.8. Everything seems to work fine, except the last "verification" steps:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Ewan:~ ewandelanoy$ /opt/local/bin/identify -list font
-bash: /opt/local/bin/identify: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro-de-Ewan:~ ewandelanoy$ display -display :0
-bash: display: command not found
```

Can anyone explain what’s going on here?

Comment: How did you install it ? MacPorts ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes, MacPorts, as the file INSTALL.txt recommends it